# Вывод в два столбца

Tags: c++, циклы, вывод, форматирование

Как сделать вывод в два столбца с помощью цикла do while

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
    #include<iostream.h>
  #include<iomanip.h>
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int A[10];
    int n_max = N - 1;

    int i = 0;
    while( i < N )
        cin >> A[i++];

    cout << "vash massiv: " << endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        cout << A[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    for( int i = N - 2;  i >= 0; i-- )
        if( A[i] > A[n_max] )
            n_max = i;

    int buf  = A[n_max];
    A[n_max] = A[N - 1];
    A[N - 1] = buf;

    cout << "massiv posle zameni: " << endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        cout << A[i] << '\t';  //?
    cout << endl;

    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

(Вывод полученного массива)

Comment: Что за говнокод ты написал в директивах включения? Что значит "вывод в два столбца"? Тут экстрасенсы что ли по-твоему сидят? Консольный вывод осуществляется построчно слева направо, переопределить это можно работая с библиотекой windows.h, если не ошибаюсь. Сам никогда этим не извращался.

Comment: Бомбануло у человека 

Comment: А насколько обязательно с именно `do-while`? С `for` можно? и еще - как именно - первая строка - 1 и 2, вторая - 3 и 4, ... - это тоже вывод в 2 столбца. Или выводить надо первый столбец - 1 2 3..., а потом второй N/2  N/2+1 ...?

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον вас не просили оскорблять человека. Молчите.

Comment: @nathanprescott, в каком месте тут оскорбление?

Answer (score 3):

Выводить все равно надо физически построчно, поэтому - так:

```
for(int i = 0, j = (N+1)/2; i < (N+1)/2; ++i, ++j) {
    cout << a[i] << "\t";
    if (j < N) cout << a[j];
    cout << endl;
    }
```